# how to return a model class to customized XML?

Tags: xml, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have MVC4 application with EF5. In my application I'm returning my class to XML format. Such as follow.

```
<ProjectDTO.DetailProject>
<Id>1</Id>
<Name>project1</Name>
</ProjectDTO.DetailProject>
```

But I think this structure is inefficient so I want to change to something like

```
<Project name="project1" id="1">
```

I want to make I XML elements to stored in attributes field.
My current code for generating XML is to just returning DTO class at web api controller. How do I get controller to set my XML?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some attributes in your `dto` class, for sample:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class ProjectDTO
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

There are a lot of attributes you can use, take a look at [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).